# Unable to create containers after modifying the base image of wso2sp

Tags: python, docker, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm trying to install Python in my WSO2SP containers.

This is my Dockerfile present in /alpine/base directory.

```
# set base docker image to adoptopenjdk alpine based docker image
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jdk8u212-b03-alpine
MAINTAINER WSO2 Docker Maintainers "dev@wso2.org”

# set user configurations
ARG USER=wso2carbon
ARG USER_ID=802
ARG USER_GROUP=wso2
ARG USER_GROUP_ID=802
ARG USER_HOME=/home/${USER}
# set dependant files directory
ARG FILES=./files
# set wso2 product configurations
ARG WSO2_SERVER=wso2sp
ARG WSO2_SERVER_VERSION=4.4.0
ARG WSO2_SERVER_PACK=${WSO2_SERVER}-${WSO2_SERVER_VERSION}
ARG WSO2_SERVER_HOME=${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}
ENV ENV=${USER_HOME}"/.ashrc"

# install required packages
RUN  apk add --update --no-cache netcat-openbsd && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# create a user group and a user
RUN  addgroup -g ${USER_GROUP_ID} ${USER_GROUP}; \
     adduser -u ${USER_ID} -D -g '' -h ${USER_HOME} -G ${USER_GROUP} ${USER} ;

# MOTD login message
RUN echo 'printf "Welcome to WSO2 Docker resources.\n\
----------------------------------\n\
The Docker container contains the WSO2 product with its latest updates,\n\
which are under the End User License Agreement (EULA) 2.0.\n\
Read more about EULA 2.0 (https://wso2.com/licenses/wso2-update/2.0).\n"' > "$ENV"

# copy the wso2 product distribution to user's home directory
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 ${FILES}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}/ ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/
# copy the Kafka client jars to the product home
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 ${FILES}/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1.jar ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}/lib/
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 ${FILES}/kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}/lib/
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 ${FILES}/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}/lib/
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 ${FILES}/scala-library-2.11.8.jar ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}/lib/
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 ${FILES}/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}/lib/
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 ${FILES}/zkclient-0.10.jar ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}/lib/
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 ${FILES}/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}/lib/
COPY --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 ${FILES}/mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar ${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER_PACK}/lib/

# set environment variables
ENV WSO2_SERVER_HOME=${WSO2_SERVER_HOME} \
    WORKING_DIRECTORY=${USER_HOME}

# set the user and work directory
USER ${USER_ID}
WORKDIR ${USER_HOME}

USER root
RUN apk add --update \
    python3 \
    python-dev \
    py-pip \
    build-base \
    vim \
  && pip install virtualenv \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
  && pip install flask
```

I'm able to build base, dashboard, editor and worker images successfully.

When I try to bring up the containers, this is the error that repeats until the `Mount verification timed out` message appears.

```
Waiting for all volumes to be mounted...
Directory /home/wso2carbon/wso2-config-volume does not exist
Waiting for the volume to be mounted...
Retrying...
Directory /home/wso2carbon/wso2-config-volume does not exist
Waiting for the volume to be mounted...
Retrying...
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Nothing in the code you've included produces those error messages.  Typically in Docker everything would be mounted before the single main container process starts up, so waiting for a mount to happen isn't necessarily useful.

Comment: The containers for the dashboard, editor, manager and worker do not come up for alpine even without including Python installation lines. This is the core of the problem.